# How correctly specify ReactJS license in my SPA repo and contribute it?

Tags: mit

If I understand correctly, ReactJS ships with MIT FB license.

I will plan create a repository with code based on using ReactJS as dependency in my SPA.

In my app, I want want to use another open-source license, but React MIT lisence require link to original copyright. Should I:

- use text of original license
- link it in each file of project
- or can I create some like 3rdparty.txt in root of project and
  copy/paste the original lisence text from github (react/LICENSE at
  master · facebook/react · GitHub)

What is a correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to keep the notice in the source files.

You do not need to put anything in your application.